# Generating daily report on very big tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very simple query that gives me daily report for how much rows are there for each day:

```
SELECT  DATE(action_date),COUNT(id)
FROM  call_history
GROUP  BY DATE( action_date)
```

(action_date is a datetime type column)

On tables with 100,000 rows this query takes around 0.5 seconds,

On other table I have with currently 1,858,075 it takes around 3 seconds, this table is keep growing and soon the query will take minutes...

using the `DATE` function with the `GROUP BY` is basically removing my indexes and causing the queries to be very slow.

Is there any way to make this faster beside adding a `DATE` column to my table?

the problem with adding a `DATE` column is that I'm generating my reports by hours/days/years and more and I can't have a column for each type.

Thanks,
Rami.

Comment: Is there an index on the action_date field? And what is the result of `EXPLAIN SELECT  DATE(action_date),COUNT(id) FROM call_history GROUP  BY DATE( action_date);`

Comment: Yes there is an index, res:
1 | SIMPLE      | call_history | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1858075 | Using temporary; Using filesort

Comment: Just a little insight which I learned a few days ago: Having the right index alone might not be enough. Sometimes the MySQL optimizer does not choose the right index for a query. In my case it helped to tell MySQL which index to use by adding ...USE INDEX(...)... in my query.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that you have a calendar table with dates in it.  The following query might run faster:

```
SELECT c.thedate,
       (select count(*)
        from call_history ch
        where ch.action_date >= c.thedate and
              ch.action_date < c.thedate + interval 1 day
       ) as cnt
FROM calendar c
oRDER BY c.thedate;
```

By replacing the aggregation with a correlated subquery, you can convince MySQL to actually use the index.

MySQL is pretty bad about using indexes for `group by`.  You can try using a trick with the dates, which is really yucky.  If you store the dates as strings, say YYYYMMDDHHMISS, then you can create substring indexes on the date field.  This is the closest that MySQL gets to functional indexes (or indexes on computed columns).  Then you would be able to express the query as:

```
SELECT  DATE(action_date), COUNT(id)
FROM  call_history
GROUP BY LEFT(UglyDateAsStringField, 8);
```

And it might use an index.

Comment: I'm not using a calendar table since I don't care about not displaying 0 data rows,
can calendar actually help with the performance? I was thinking the other way,

The GROUP BY LEFT is giving me the same times as using SUBSTRING or DATE

Comment: @user2270158 . . . That's nice.  This isn't about displaying rows with no data, it is about convincing MySQL to use an index.  You can filter out the rows with a zero value using `having cnt = 0` if you want.

Comment: I have generated a calendar database ran the query, it's taking much longer, over 6 seconds for my small (100,000) table :$

Comment: Can you tell if that query is using the index?  I can think of two other possible solutions (neither appealing):  split the date and time into two fields and keep a summary table updated using triggers.